# PHP Multi-Level Menu for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to style a multi-level menu for a Wordpress site. I have the HTML and CSS code, also a JS onclick toggle for the lower level menus.
I've tried following guides on the internet but it doesn't work as I'd like since I want my second/lower level menus to appear on click and not on hover.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Fast Checks</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Link Number One</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#one"  class="trigger">Link Number Two <i class="ico ico-arrow"></i> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#l-1">Link Number One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#l-2">Link Number Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#l-3">Link Number Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Number Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Number Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Recover Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ProfileHub</a></li>
        <li>
            <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Try It Free</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success-border btn-sm">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your javascript code too.

Comment: Sorry, actually it's not JS, it's just the data-toggle bootstrap command. But still, I can't find a way of doing this.

Comment: What I don't know is how to fetch the menu from wordpress and add the styling to it, in this case the already existing "dropdown" "dropdown-menu" etc. classes.